# Load text file into structure, check for searched word in list and delete from text file

Tags: python

My problem is that I want to load and split data from text file into some python structure. From every split find exact line that starts with some word and check if It exists in list. If It exists delete It from file. Some records may have the same code, but will always have different data. Example:

```
Data.txt
0|A
1|B
5|C1
5|C2
7|User: 1111
0|D
1|E
5|F
7|User: 2222
0|G
1|I
5|J
7|User: 3333
```

And I want to load this file with every 0| so nested list should look like this:

```
[
 [
0|A
1|B
5|C1
5|C2
7|User: 1111
]
[
0|D
1|E
5|F
7|User: 2222
]
[
0|G
1|I
5|J
7|User: 3333
 ]
]
```

Then I have a list with user codes. If a user code exists in this list I want to delete this child-list. So I want to take the 3333 from 7|User: 3333 and check If it exists in list with user codes. Then after this check my nested list should look like this.

```
[
 [
0|A
1|B
5|C1
5|C2
7|User: 1111
]
[
0|D
1|E
5|F
7|User: 2222
 ]
]
```

and then I want to overwrite the loaded text file with this data:

```
Data.txt after
0|A
1|B
5|C1
5|C2
7|User: 1111
0|D
1|E
5|F
7|User: 2222
```

The problem is I don't really know how to do It all especially the loading part. Right now I only tried to load the file into nested list like this.

```
main_list = []
with open('input.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        while not line.startswith('7|'):
            if line.startswith('0|'):
                help_list = []
            help_list.append(line)
        main_list.append(help_list)

print(main_list)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is number 7 always related to the `User:` entry?

Comment: @nonDucor Yes. :)

Comment: Can you update your question with whatever you have tried so far in terms of code, so we can help you where you got stuck?

Comment: @nonDucor I added the code that I have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the records will be excluded by user and they can have repeated "fields", we use a dictionary with two entries: `data`, which is a list of lines in a record as you had on your question, and `user`, which saves the line with the user id (this line is also present in `data`, so the order when writing out is always preserved). The function `create_record` below creates this structure. If you are using python >= 3.7, you could use a `dataclass` to have a solution that is more elegant.

The code below first reads all the records in memory, then remove the ones with users that we are not interested and finally write the output in another file. Unless you have a **very** large number of records, this approach works well.

```py
def create_record():  # Represents a record in the file, making the user line easily accessible
    return {'user': '', 'data': []}

current_record = None
records = []
# Note: well-formedness checks are not done
with open('Data.txt', 'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue  # Skip empty lines, particularly empty lines in the end of the file
        if line.startswith('0|'):
            current_record = create_record()
            records.append(current_record)
        elif line.startswith('7|'):
            current_record['user'] = line   # Record the user line to make searching more efficient
        current_record['data'].append(line)

# Let's assume your list of user codes is a series of strings.
user_ids_to_delete = ['2222', '0000']
users_to_delete = {f'7|User: {user_id}' for user_id in user_ids_to_delete }  # Sets are used because checking set membership is faster

remaining_records = [record for record in records if record['user'] not in users_to_delete]

# Finally, save the file with the deleted users
with open('CleanData.txt', 'w') as fh:
    fh.writelines((f'{line}\n' for record in remaining_records for line in record['data']))
```

Comment: I wanted to make it on nested list because there may be some records with the same starting code. For example there may be two 11 and dict will only left the first record instead of both.

Comment: Good point! Please improve your example to show that. Would you have two fields starting with 7 on the same record then (i.e. two user ids in a single record?). In that case, would you delete the record in case any of the two users matched your list?

Comment: luckily there will always be one record with 7 as user id and with 0 as starting record, but as I said there may be some double records with the same code but different data. Added to example. ;)

Comment: @neekitit, answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it, using [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html):

```py
from __future__ import annotations  # not needed PY 3.10+

from dataclasses import dataclass, field, InitVar
from pathlib import Path
from typing import TextIO


@dataclass
class User:
    id: int = field(init=False)
    codes: dict[str, int] = field(default_factory=dict, init=False)

    def add_id(self, line: str):
        id = self.id = int(line.rsplit(':', 1)[-1])
        return id

    def add_code(self, line: str):
        num, code = line.split('|', 1)
        self.codes[code] = int(num)

    def __str__(self):
        record = [f'{num}|{code}' for code, num in self.codes.items()]
        record.append(f'7|User: {self.id}')
        return '\n'.join(record)


@dataclass
class UserDict(dict):
    file_or_name: InitVar[TextIO | str]

    def __post_init__(self, file_or_name: TextIO | str):
        curr_user = User()
        contents: str = Path(file_or_name).read_text() \
            if isinstance(file_or_name, str) else file_or_name.read()

        for line in contents.splitlines():
            if line.startswith('7|'):
                id_ = curr_user.add_id(line)
                self[id_] = curr_user
                curr_user = User()
            elif line.strip():
                curr_user.add_code(line)

    def delete(self, *ids_to_delete: int):
        for id_ in ids_to_delete:
            self.pop(id_, None)

    def __repr__(self):
        prefix = self.__class__.__name__
        spaces = ' ' * (len(prefix) + 1)
        users_repr = f',\n{spaces}'.join(f'{id_}={user!r}'
                                         for id_, user in self.items())
        return f"{prefix}({users_repr})"

    def save_to_file(self, filename: str):
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(self))

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(str(u) for u in self.values())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from io import StringIO

    # use a file-like object for simplicity
    file_obj = StringIO("""\
0|A
1|B
5|C1
5|C2
7|User: 1111
0|D
1|E
5|F
7|User: 2222
0|G
1|I
5|J
7|User: 3333
    """)

    users = UserDict(file_obj)

    # uncomment to read from file
    # users = UserDict('Data.txt')

    print(repr(users))
    print()

    user_ids_to_delete = [3333]
    users.delete(*user_ids_to_delete)

    new_file_contents = str(users)
    print(new_file_contents)

    # uncomment to update file
    # users.save_to_file('Data.txt')
```

Out:

```
UserDict(1111=User(id=1111, codes={'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C1': 5, 'C2': 5}),
         2222=User(id=2222, codes={'D': 0, 'E': 1, 'F': 5}),
         3333=User(id=3333, codes={'G': 0, 'I': 1, 'J': 5}))

0|A
1|B
5|C1
5|C2
7|User: 1111
0|D
1|E
5|F
7|User: 2222
```